# What is the proper syntax code in using datetimepicker in visual studio c#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Can anyone tell me what is the proper syntax code in using datetimepicker that would be saved directly to my Microsoft sql 2005? I'm using visual studio 2008 c#.

Here is my code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MJ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlDataAdapter dad = new SqlDataAdapter();
    // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    // cmd.Connection = conn;
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;

    string dateStr = Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker1.Text);
    dad.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblSchools (School_Name, Province, City, Brgy, Lot_Num, Area, Mem_Date_Rec, Cenro) VALUES(@School_Name, @Province, @City, @Brgy, @Lot_Num, @Area, @Mem_Date_Rec, @Cenro", conn);
    dad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@School_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
    dad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Province", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.Text;
    dad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
    dad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Brgy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
    dad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Lot_Num", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
    dad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Area", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox6.Text;
    dad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Mem_Date_Rec", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
    dad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Cenro", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox8.Text;    

    conn.Open();
    dad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

The problem here is the datetimepicker, in my sql server Mem_Date_Rec is a datetime, so whenever I try to run it and save something on my database,
    dad.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Keeps on saying "Incorrect syntax near '@Cenro'."

Can anyone help me out here please, it would be a really great help.

Comment: Why cmd.Parameters instead of da.InsertCommand.Parameters? Moreover cmd itself is useless because you don't set any SQL command/query to execute...

Comment: well i've been researching about it and tried everything i can find in the internet

Comment: You are missing a ) in your SQL. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you try to insert your parameter to `dad.InsertCommand` command not `cmd` command.

```
dad.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Mem_Date_Rec", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

Because your `dad.InsertCommand` has a parameter called `@Mem_Date_Rec`, not `cmd`. I have no idea what is your `cmd` for exactly. It's useless this case. **You can't add a parameter value in an SqlCommand that doesn't have any parameter definition**.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` like;

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   //
}
```

If you want to write a proper syntax code, you need start reading a book, articles, blogs, examples etc..

Comment: @user3449186 What? `o.O` But you try to insert it `@Mem_Date_Rec` as a parameter even if you don't have any command text in your `cmd`.

Comment: now its telling me that the error is near syntax @Cenro

Answer (score 0):

edit

You're missing something in your SQL. Change this:

```
> dad.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblSchools
> (School_Name, Province, City, Brgy, Lot_Num, Area, Mem_Date_Rec,
> Cenro) VALUES(@School_Name, @Province, @City, @Brgy, @Lot_Num, @Area,
> @Mem_Date_Rec, @Cenro", conn);
```

To this

```
dad.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblSchools (School_Name, Province, City, Brgy, Lot_Num, Area, Mem_Date_Rec, Cenro) VALUES(@School_Name, @Province, @City, @Brgy, @Lot_Num, @Area, @Mem_Date_Rec, @Cenro)", conn);
```

INSERT INTO table (columns) values (value)

you had: INSERT INTO table (columns) values (value

Comment: cmd was only a trial, i was searching the internet about it and found something like that.

Comment: I amended my answer, I found your issue